# how to add 1 table that do not have any match in union that already combine 2 query

Tags: ms-access

I make union that combine 2 query...[qry_soldering] and [qry_smtline]...

```sql
SELECT [PIC], [Total seconds], [SortByWeek], [date_worked_smt],[day]
FROM [qry_smt_line]
UNION 
SELECT [PIC], [total time], [SortByWeek], [date_worked_soldering],[day]
FROM [qry_soldering]
ORDER BY [PIC] DESC;
```

How can I add new table [tbl_day] in that union? Is that possible?

Comment: Show example raw data and desired output.

Comment: the one I upload was my example, that combine qry_soldering and qry_smtline..... so what i want is add tbl_day in this union. Because my data that i put "day" can't be edited... so i think wanna add table in the union

Comment: There is no upload. Files cannot be uploaded. Data cannot be edited in UNION query no matter if you use table or query. Need to provide table structure if you want more help. Do you want tbl_day as another UNION line?

Comment: yes, like a new row table

Comment: sorry that i'm not eloquent in english

Comment: Edit question to show what fields you want from tbl_day and in what column they belong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a third query to union with the two first - and consider using *UNION ALL*:

```
SELECT [PIC], [Total seconds], [SortByWeek], [date_worked_smt], [day]
FROM [qry_smt_line]
UNION ALL
SELECT [PIC], [total time], [SortByWeek], [date_worked_soldering], [day]
FROM [qry_soldering]
UNION ALL
SELECT [PicField], [TimeField], [WeekField], [DateField], [DayField]
ORDER BY [PIC] DESC;
```

Comment: pop up alert said "query input must contain at least one table or query"